# Doctrine ORM Issue: [Semantical Error] The annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: doctrine-orm, mezzio

Issue I am encountering as of the moment.

```
Error Encounter: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id_users" in property Users\Entity\User::$id_users does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

My Entity PHP Code:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Users\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */

class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id_users
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id_users", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id_users;

    /**
     * @ORM\Username
     * @ORM\Column(type="varchar", name="username", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Password
     * @ORM\Column(type="varchar", name="password", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Email
     * @ORM\Column(type="varchar", name="email", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Status
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="status", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Date_created
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_created", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $date_created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Date_updated
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_updated", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $date_updated;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdUsers()
    {
        return $this->id_users;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id_users
     */
    public function setIdUsers($id_users): void
    {
        $this->id_users = $id_users;
    }



    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username): void
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $status
     */
    public function setStatus($status): void
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->date_created;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date_created
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setDateCreated(\DateTime $date_created = null): void
    {
        if (!$date_created && empty($this->getIdUser())) {
            $this->date_created = new \DateTime("now");
        } else {
            $this->date_created = $date_created;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateUpdated(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->date_updated;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date_updated
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setDateUpdated(\DateTime $date_updated = null): void
    {
        if ($date_updated) {
            $this->date_updated = new \DateTime("now");
        } else {
            $this->date_updated = $date_updated;
        }
    }



}
```

Here is a snippet of my Config Provider Snippet:

```
    public function getDoctrineEntities() : array
    {
        return [
            'driver' => [
                'orm_default' => [
                    'class' => MappingDriverChain::class,
                    'drivers' => [
                        'Users\Entity' => 'user_entity',
                    ],
                ],
                'user_entity' => [
                    'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                    'cache' => 'array',
                    'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/Entity'],
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

I've already tried to rename an update my labels and variables but I can't seem to eliminate this issue. Is there a configuration I missed out? I'm using the latest version of Zend Expressive. Any suggestions and comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ORM\Id_users` annotation is not valid. The correct annotation for the id field is `@ORM\Id`. It is not related to the name of the property, but it is there to indicate the property is the primary key.

> The annotated instance variable will be marked as entity identifier, the primary key in the database. This annotation is a marker only and has no required or optional attributes. For entities that have multiple identifier columns each column has to be marked with @Id.

As Flying is saying, you should remove `@ORM\{property name}` for all other properties. A complete list of valid annotation can be found in the [doctrine ocs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#index).

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed no such annotations in Doctrine.

You need to remove **all** annotations that looks like `@ORM\{column name}` from your class.

For example one that Doctrine is mentioned into error message `@ORM\Id_users` that belongs to `$id_users` property. If you will remove it - Doctrine will report error about next one `@ORM\Username` and so on.